# how to get the synchronizationGroup names in SUP 2.2?

Tags: ios, iphone, sup

Im using SUP2.2 SP06 version. My question is how to get the synchronizationGroup names in iOS ??? I found some methods in generated DB class. Which one I have to use it and how ??

Answer (score 0):

In Win32 code, I find the method GetAllSynchronizationGroups in the generated DB class. There should be something similar in the generated iOS DB class...